# How to edit android build.prop in my app

Tags: android

I would like a sample code that would edit the build.prop file from a button that a user hits. Example: If the user wants to change orientation on a mini pc device to portrait they would have to edit the ro.sf.rotation to 180 or 360. I want this in my app so it can be changed by a simple mouse click rather them downloading an editor and having them change it themselves. I know they will have to restart and have root. Root will be required for this app i am making.

Answer (score 0):

That's actually very simple.

Once you have the exact path of the build.prop on the Android system, you create a FileInputStream with that path, use some type of tokeniser to parse the individual items in there and change the rotation element, then use a FileOutputStream to re-write back to the file.

Comment: Can you give an example?